# Array push is overwriting previously pushed data

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, javascript-objects, angular8

I am trying to build a sample Restaurants app using Angular 8. I am using @Input() to pass individual restaurant data as object from the parent component to RestaurantCardComponent for displaying. Each individual card in RestaurantCardComponent has an 'Add to favorites' button which which should push that particular restaurants into a favorites array in the User model class. However when I try pushing the object, the first object is pushed without any issue but thereafter clicking on 'Add to favorites' just replaces the previously pushed object. Below is the HTML code for the CardViewComponent.

```
<app-restaurant-card [restaurant]="collection" *ngFor="let collection of collections"></app-restaurant-card>
```

Here is the RestaurantCardComponent typescript code:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { faHeart } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { AuthServiceService } from '../services/auth-service.service';
import { User } from '../user';
import { RouterService } from '../services/router.service';
import { Restaurant } from '../restaurant';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-restaurant-card',
  templateUrl: './restaurant-card.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./restaurant-card.component.css']
})
export class RestaurantCardComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() restaurant: Restaurant;
  faHeart = faHeart;
  user: User = new User();

  constructor(private authService: AuthServiceService, private routerService: RouterService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // console.log(this.restaurant);
    this.authService.getUserData(parseInt(this.authService.getBearerToken())).subscribe(
      data => this.user = data,
      error => console.log(error.message));
  }

  addToFavourites() {

    this.user.favourites.push(this.restaurant);
    this.authService.updateUserData(this.user).subscribe(
      updatedData => console.log(updatedData),
      error => console.log(error.message)
    );

  }

}
```

How can I add the restaurants to the favorites array without replacing the previously pushed array?

Comment: You create a new user in each instance of the component. I think you should make the `user` field an `Input()` and pass it from the parent component so the User would be common for each card

Comment: what does your `updateUserData`-method look like?

Comment: I agree with @SebastianKaczmarek. If you have 100 restaurants you will send to the backend 100 request for get user info for each component. And I think it can solve your problem, because you will have 1 instance of user and on the child components you will work with the reference of your user object

Comment: Consider looking into the presentation and container component pattern (a.k.a smart and dumb components). You probably want to have a user service that will store the favourites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new service called maybe UserService or add the property "user" to the AuthService not to the component, if you add the user to the component you will have an instance for each component.